# Why am i getting this error : Cannot reference 'ViewHolder.itemView' before supertype constructor has been called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a blog post using recycler view and firebase database.
Getting error in itemView. It says cannot refer before supertype constructor has been called.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

```
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;


    public BlogViewHolder(View view) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView = mView;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        TextView post_title=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_title.setText(title);

    }

    public void setDesc(String desc){
        TextView post_desc=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_desc.setText(desc);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is itemView?. I think your code should be this:  super(view) then view = mView

Comment: And why do you want to use `mView.findViewById()` instead of `view.findViewById()` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your screenshot, `itemView` is final variable. So You can not assign the value to it.

In **ViewHolder** class you can change the minor changes:

```
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    TextView post_title, post_desc;

    public BlogViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = View;
        post_title=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_desc=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the error is resolved but still I'm unable to retrieve data from firebase.

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot it says you cannot assign a value to a final variable, which indeed you can't. You want to assign `mView`, so it would be the other way,

```
mView = itemView
```

Answer (score 0):

The way the RecyclerView.ViewHolder works is that you specify in onCreateViewHolder the layout for the ViewHolder and the view parameter corresponding to that layout is passed for you inside the ViewHolder.

In your case, there is no sense to re-allocate the view parameter to **mView**.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    BlogViewHolder bvh = new BlogViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false)
    );
}
```

In the above method specify the layout row in **row_layout**, make sure you pass the context as the parameter when creating your adapter.

The correct implementation of your ViewHolder should be:

```
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private final TextView post_title;
    private final TextView post_desc;

    public BlogViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        post_title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_desc=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.post_title)
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        post_title.setText(title);
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc){
        post_desc.setText(desc);
    }
}
```

By saving the fields in the constructor you don't call multiple times the expensive function **findViewById** in the **onBindViewHolder** method.

Back to your question, the **view** parameter here is the inflated layout of row_layout. On the other hand the **itemView** is just a variable saved in the Android's ViewHolder after you call the super method and in your case is a shorthand for the view. You could use the itemView as a shorthand for **mView** but I consider that allocating in the constructor is better. Also the itemView in android view holder implementation is marked as final:

```
public final View itemView;
```

And this is why you can't and shouldn't re-allocate it.

Comment: Okay, did the same thing, used `parent.getContext()` in LayoutInflator, but still unable to fetch the data from firebase database.

Comment: We need to see some code related to your firebase integration to be able to help you.